# adding spaces inside string using regex sub

Tags: python, regex

I have a string I want to split into 2-digit pieces. I tried using regex like so:

```
import re
s = "123456789"
t = re.sub('..', ".. ", s)
print(t)
```

I expected to get `12 34 56 78 9` but instead I got `'.. .. .. .. 9'`. The `9` does not bother me, because I know I will have an even number of digits, but how can I tell the `re.sub` to not replace the actual digit with a dot?

*using python shell 3.5.1*

**EDIT**

checked all 3 answers, and they all work, but the findall seems to be faster (and more elegant IMO ;p ):

```
import time
import re

s = "43256711233214432"

i = 10000
start = time.time()
while i:
    i -= 1
    re.sub('(..)', r"\1 ", s)    
end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start
print("using r\"\\1 \"    : ", elapsed)

i = 10000
start = time.time()
while i:
    re.sub('..', r"\g<0> ", s)
    i -= 1
end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start
print("using r\"\g<0> \" : ", elapsed)

i = 10000
start = time.time()
while i:
    ' '.join(re.findall(r'..|.', s))
    i -= 1
end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start
print("using findall   : ", elapsed)
```

> using r"\1 "    :  0.25461769104003906
>
> using r"\g<0> " :  0.09374403953552246
>
> using findall   :  0.015610456466674805

**2nd EDIT:** is there a better way (or any way...) doing this *without* regex?

Comment: You timing analysis is weird. `\1` and `\g<0>` do pretty much the same and should be equally fast. Using IPython's `%timeit` function gives me 8.5µs for both `sub` approaches, 2.0µs for `findall` and 1.5µs for `range(0, len, 2)`

Comment: @tobias_k don't know... I run this script about 10 times, every time "findall" was 1st, "g" 2nd and "\1" 3rd

Comment: And what happens if you test them in a different order, say first `\g`, then `\1`? `findall` is fastest (except `range`), no arguing about that. BTW, when I run your script it's more closely to `%timeit`, with `\g` and `\1` coming out nearly identically.

Comment: I see minor changes, but not sure about them... I had it run 10 times in a row, and did a mean. g came faster by 0.2 both times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` also,

```
>>> s = "123456789"
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'..|.', s))
'12 34 56 78 9'
>>>
```

`r'..|.'` regex matches two chars or a single character (first preference goes to `..` and then `.`)

Comment: ... but impractical - why achieve the result with 2 steps (`re.findall` + `join`), when you can do that using 1 step (`re.sub`). Moreover, a regex with an alternation performance is slower than without.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do yo mean by 'a regex with an alternation performance is slower...'? By my tests, this method is faster by far

Comment: Faster than `re.sub('..', r"\g<0> ", s)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can just refer to the whole match with `\g<0>` **backreference** in the replacement string pattern (where you cannot use *regular expression* patterns):

```
re.sub('..', r"\g<0> ", s)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/a1Lisg):

```
import re
s = "12345678"
print(re.sub('..', r"\g<0> ", s))
```

See [`re.sub` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Answer (score 2):

In a regex, `.` means any character.  In replacement text, it means a period.  If you want to capture characters as a group in your regex, you need to put parens around them.  You can reference the first such group in the replacement text by using `\1`:

```
>>> re.sub('(..)', r"\1 ", s)
'12 34 56 78 9'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List Comprehensions too,

```
>>> s='123456789'
>>> res=[s[index:index+2] for index,x in enumerate(s) if index % 2==0]
['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
```

Comment: but this gives list, not a string, and there are no spaces

Comment: @noob It gives the same result as `findall`, you just have to `' '.join`. However, compared to the other solutions it's kind of clunky.

Comment: Instead of `enumerate` and that modulo check, I suggest you use `' '.join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))`